# jquery active accordion panel can no longer be set with a css selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have been using Jquery UI for a long time (years) to generate an accordion. The active panel was set by adding the .active class as specified in below code:

```
$(".accordion-default").accordion({
        header      : "h3",
        icons       : false,
        collapsible : false,
        autoHeight  : false,
        active      : "h3.active",
    });
```

This worked until I upgraded to jquery 1.12.4 and jquery ui 1.12.1. There is no longer a reference to using a class selector in the jquery ui API documentation.

Is this no longer supported (why?!) and can anyone recommend a work around that achieve the same result?